# is_file() and is_dir() don't work

Tags: php

I'm writing a class for file hashing but I got stuck at the beginning.

```
class fileHashing
{
    private $start_path = '../../../test';
    private $log_path   = '../../../test/log';
    private $log_file   = 'fileHash.xyz';

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open();
    }

    private function open() {
        $files_list = scandir($this->start_path);
        print_r($files_list);
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
        foreach ($files_list as $key => $element) {
            if (is_file($element)) {
                echo "FILE: " . $element . PHP_EOL;

            } elseif (is_dir($element)) {
                echo "DIR: " . $element . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                echo "NONE: " . $element . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}

$a = new fileHashing();
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => fileupload.php
    [3] => log
    [4] => test1.php
    [5] => tsconfig.json
)
DIR: .
DIR: ..
FILE: fileupload.php
NONE: log
NONE: test1.php
NONE: tsconfig.json
```

`log` is a folder and it's not recognized as it and both `test1.php` and `tsconfig.json` are not recognized as files.
Am I missing something about `scandir()` / `is_file()` / `is_dir()`?

Comment: maybe you should use `$this->start_path . '/' . $element` for `is_dir` and `is_file`

Comment: Could those files be symbolic links? Try `is_link()`

Comment: @Philipp I know I was missing something about the functions; I thougt they analize the filename distinguishing between `.ext => file` `no ext => folder` so that the filename was enough. Thanks Philipp, now it works. Can you tell me how they then analyze the files/dir? Checking the slashes `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also append the `start_path` to your filename inside `is_file` and `is_dir`. Could be done like this

```
private function open() {
    $files_list = scandir($this->start_path);
    print_r($files_list);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
    foreach ($files_list as $key => $element) {
        $file = $this->start_path . '/' . $element;
        if (is_file($file)) {
            echo "FILE: " . $element . PHP_EOL;

        } elseif (is_dir($file)) {
            echo "DIR: " . $element . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo "NONE: " . $element . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:-

```
if (filetype($this->start_path . '/' . $element) == "dir") {
  // dir
}elseif(filetype($this->start_path . '/' . $element) == "file") {
  // file
}
// or this way
if (is_dir($this->start_path . '/' . $element)) {
  // dir
}elseif(is_file($this->start_path . '/' . $element)) {
  // file
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ranjeet, the problem was the one highlighted by @Philipp but nice alternative solution! +1 'cause I didn't know about `filetype()`